# Thread, progressbar howto

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I'm using `XslCompiledTransform` to transform XML file to HTML.
XML file is not so short, so transformation is waste a lot of time.

My code:

```
 xslTransform.Transform(fi.FullName, TMP_TRANSFORMED_XML_PATH);
 webBrowser1.Navigate(TMP_TRANSFORMED_XML_PATH);
```

So I want to use progress-bar or (better) progress icon (dialog?) which is not bound to a form.

The problem is that I have two forms. 
The 1st one has a list of items and a button, when item selected and button is pressed, 2nd form is shown (not modal), XML file transforms and it's shown in WebBrowser control.

In 2nd form constructor I call `XslCompiledTransform.Load`, initialize controls and then call `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`.

In a second form I also have buttons to navigate between 1st form list items. So when I press '>' then the next element from 1st form is selected, and 2nd form's elements are reloaded - e.g. some text changed and XslCompiledTransform.Transform() is called again for a new XML file.

**So, how to organize progress bar while 2nd form is loading each time?**

From 1st Form :

```
private void OpenSecondForm()
{
    if (formTwo == null)
    {
            formTwo = new FormTwo(this, culture, params);
            formTwo .Show();
    }
    else
    {
            if (formTwo .IsDisposed)
            {
                formTwo = new FormTwo(this, culture, params);
                formTwo .Show();
            }
            else
            {
                formTwo .Reinitialaze(culture, invoice);
            }
            formTwo .BringToFront();
    }

}

public void SelectRow(int moveTo)
{
    try
    {
      /*navigate on list here */
  /* ... */

OpenSecondForm();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "ERROR"); }
}
```

2nd form:

```
public FormTwo(Form parent, CultureInfo cultr, string params)
{
    culture = cultr;

    parentForm = parent;
    rm = new ResourceManager("MyProject.Resource", typeof(FormOne).Assembly);
    InitializeComponent();

    xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslTransform.Load(XSL_TRANSFORM_SCHEMA_NAME);

    ReInitialazeAll();

}

internal void Reinitialaze(CultureInfo cultr, string params)
{
    culture = cultr;

    ReInitialazeAll();
}

private void ReInitialazeAll()
{
    SelectDatabaseData();

    InitCaptions();
    InitForms();

}

private void InitForms()
{
    EnableDisableButtons();
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<HTML><BODY></BODY></HTML>";

    FillXmlData();
}

private void FillXmlData()
{
    xslTransform.Transform(fi.FullName, TMP_TRANSFORMED_XML_PATH);
    webBrowser1.Navigate(TMP_TRANSFORMED_XML_PATH);
}
```

I've tried to create a thread to execute these FillXmlData. But my forms is still not accessible while xml is transforming.

Comment: What size is the XML file? What does your XSLT look like?

Comment: You should consider splitting this question into two - one for the XSLT performance issues and one for the progress bar.

Comment: OK, Forget about xsl->xml. How to organize progress animation?

Comment: `I've tried to create a thread to execute these FillXmlData` - where? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the XML transformation (and any other lengthy non-UI loading operations) on a separate thread. Something like this:

```
public FormTwo(Form parent, CultureInfo cultr, string params)
{
    culture = cultr;

    parentForm = parent;
    rm = new ResourceManager("MyProject.Resource", typeof(FormOne).Assembly);

    InitializeComponent();

    // Show the progress bar
    this.ProgressBar.Visible = true;

    // Load on another thread
    Thread loadingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TransformXml));
    loadingThread.Start();
}

private void TransformXml()
{
    xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslTransform.Load(XSL_TRANSFORM_SCHEMA_NAME);

    ReInitialazeAll();
}
```

Note: This assumes your progress bar is named `ProgressBar`.

However, you need to be aware that you cannot access UI elements on another thread, so the call to `ReInitialazeAll()` (which contains a typo) needs to be invoked on the UI thread. This can be accomplished safely by doing something like:

```
private void ReInitialazeAll()
{
    // Make sure we're running on the UI thread
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(ReInitialazeAll));

        return;
    }

    // Hide the progress bar
    this.ProgressBar.Visible = false;

    // ... execute UI-related code
}
```

This should give you a decent enough start that you can work from.